# Access common view for different models with same columns

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor, view

I am working on an MVC application, which has the stages D1, D2, D3 and D4 and we will load/edit the each stages from the application.

Right now, I have created separate models and separate views for each stage model like below and utilizing it. But for code reuse, I would like to use common view for all stages (D1, D2, D3 and D4) since all the stages contains same columns.

I have an idea to implement by creating a single view-model for all four stages and utilizing but we need to edit and save the values separately. So I am struck with that point. Is there any idea to use a common view for all four models by loading and saving the data for each stage.

**Entities**

```
public partial class D1Stage : EntityBase
{
    [DisplayName("Status Indicator")]
    public byte StatusIndicatorId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status Info")]
    public string StatusInfo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Completed %")]
    [SCIRange(0, 100)]
    public decimal StageCompletion { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Is Step Mandatory")]
    public bool IsMandatory { get; set; }
}
```

And as I mentioned, `D2Stage`, `D3Stage` and `D4Stage` have exactly the same properties, for example for `D2Stage`:

```
public partial class D2Stage : EntityBase
{
    ... exact same properties as D1Stage 
}
```

**Views**

```
@model Brain.DAL.Entities.D1Stage
@{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusIndicators = ViewBag.StatusIndicators;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", @class = "form form-horizontal" }))
{
    <div class="form-body">
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Report.Id)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.SCILabelFor(model => model.StatusIndicatorId, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
            <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StatusIndicatorId, new SelectList(StatusIndicators, "Value", "Text"), "None", new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusIndicatorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.SCILabelFor(model => model.StatusInfo, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
            <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.StatusInfo, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusInfo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.SCILabelFor(model => model.StageCompletion, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
            <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                @Html.SCINumericTextBoxFor(model => model.StageCompletion, new { @class = "form-control sliderrangemintext", @style = "width:100px" })

                <div class="sliderrangemin" id="slider-range-min" style="margin-top:50px"></div>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.SCILabelFor(model => model.IsMandatory, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
            <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IsMandatory, new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true", Selected = true } }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsMandatory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And as I mentioned above, all the other views have the same content with just having  different corresponding model. For example for `D2Stage`

```
@model Brain.DAL.Entities.D2Stage
... The difference is just in model. 
... Rest of the content is exactly the same as D1Stage view
```

Comment: All models have similar properties? Create a single model or move the properties to base class and create 4 models deriving from the base model. Then also create a single view having base model as model.

Comment: It's not clear why you cannot use the same `StageViewModel` and the Same `View` for all of the stages? Maybe all you need is a `StageNumber` in your `StageViewModel` to indicate the current stage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All models have similar properties? Assuming you cannot create a single model. Then move the properties to base class and create the other models deriving from the base model. Then also create a single view having base model as model.

**Models**

```
public class MyBaseModel
{
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    public string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class ModelA: MyBaseModel{}
public class ModelB: MyBaseModel{}
```

**View**

Create a single view for the `MyBaseModel` and Put the view in the `Shared` folder and name it something like `MySharedView`:

```
@model MyNamespace.MyBaseModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Title which you can decide based on model type or get from ViewBag</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property1, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Property1, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property1, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        ... Rest of properties ...

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

**Controller**

Then in controllers, when you want to return view, specify the shared view name. For example for model `A` and the same for model `B`:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult A()
{
    var model = new ModelA() { Property1 = "A", Property2 = "A" };
    return View("MySharedView", model);
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult A(ModelA model)
{
    // SaveA(model)
    // Redirect to index
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the immediate response. I will try this out. How do i save when i click save button, it should save on separate table?

Comment: You have different actions if you need different processing. Each action receives the model that it should process.

Comment: I can extend the answer to include more options, but to be honest, the whole point is having a base class for all the models and having a single view for the the base model, not easier or not more Initiative.

Comment: You can also redesign your models, to use a single model, having all the mentioned properties + another property `public int Stage { get ;set;}` and save all data in a single table. But I assume it's an obvious solution, and you don;t want to change your model and all the tables behind.

Comment: @VigneshKumarA I believe the post answer the main concern of the question. Let me know if you have any question about it or if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you should use the pattern ModelFactory.
Create an Interface IStage with properties and method (only declaretions). Then All the class D*Stage implements IStage. So the View has as model IStage.
In this way every class can do diffent things in each method.

```
    interface IStage{

        byte StatusIndicatorId { get; set; }

        string StatusInfo { get; set; }

        decimal StageCompletion { get; set; }

        bool IsMandatory { get; set; }

    }

     public partial class D1Stage : EntityBase, IStage
     {
        [DisplayName("Status Indicator")]
        public byte StatusIndicatorId { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Status Info")]
    public string StatusInfo { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Completed %")]
    [SCIRange(0, 100)]
    public decimal StageCompletion { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Is Step Mandatory")]
    public bool IsMandatory { get; set; }

    }
```

@View

```
    @model IStage
    @{
    IEnumerable<SelectListItem> StatusIndicators = ViewBag.StatusIndicators;
    }

   @using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data", 
   @class = "form form-horizontal" }))
    {
       <div class="form-body">
           @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
           @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Report.Id)
           <div class="form-group">
               @Html.SCILabelFor(model => model.StatusIndicatorId, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
                  <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                   @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.StatusIndicatorId, new SelectList(StatusIndicators, "Value", "Text"), "None", new { @class = "form-control" })
                   @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusIndicatorId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
               </div>
           </div>
           <div class="form-group">
               @Html.SCILabelFor(model => model.StatusInfo, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
            <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.StatusInfo, new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StatusInfo, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.SCILabelFor(model => model.StageCompletion, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
            <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                @Html.SCINumericTextBoxFor(model => model.StageCompletion, new { @class = "form-control sliderrangemintext", @style = "width:100px" })

                <div class="sliderrangemin" id="slider-range-min" style="margin-top:50px"></div>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.SCILabelFor(model => model.IsMandatory, new { @class = "col-md-1 control-label" })
            <div class="input-group col-md-4">
                <div class="input-group" style="width:100%">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.IsMandatory, new List<SelectListItem>() { new SelectListItem { Text = "No", Value = "false" }, new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true", Selected = true } }, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.IsMandatory, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    }
```

In this way there's only one view.